# Integration of a huge trig function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Consider

$$\int _\frac{ -1}{\sqrt{3}} ^ \frac {1}{\sqrt {3}}\frac {x^4}{1-x^4}\arccos \left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right) \mathrm{d}x.$$

Every condition like the limits, the value which arccosine is taking is making me put $x=\tan (t) $. Thus, on simplifying we get $$\frac {\sin^4 (t)}{(1-\sin^2 (t))(1-2\sin^2 (t)}\arccos (\sin(2t)),$$ 
but from there I don't know what to do. Another approach was writing the first part as $-1+\frac {1 }{2}\left(\frac {1}{1-x^2}+\frac {1}{1+x^2}\right) $ but still I have no hope that this helps . Thus I am hoping for a better approach . Thanks!

Comment: why not integrating by parts?

Comment: There might be a way to use symmetry to simplify this.  You can try to integrating by parts.  That should make it simpler but I doubt it will just solve it.

Comment: @tired i did try but can you help me with integration after writing $+1-1$ in numeratir

Comment: Yes its not getting simplified though it looks better

Comment: you should have $\sin 2t$ not $\tan 2t$

Comment: Let's try something
We split the integral at $x=0$ so that the orignal integral reads

$$
I=I_1+I_2=\int_{-1/\sqrt{2}}^{0} f(x)dx+\int_0^{1/\sqrt{2}}f(x)dx
$$

Now we substitute $x=\pm1/y $ and note that $f(\pm1/x)=\pm f(\pm x)$ which means that

$$
I_1=-\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\quad \text{and} \quad I_2=-\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\infty}\frac{f(-x)}{x^2}
$$

But $\arccos(x)+\arccos(-x)=\pi$ so $f(x)+f(-x)=\frac{\pi }{(x^4-1)x^2}$ and

$$
I=-\pi \int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^4-1)x^2}
$$

which is elementary

Comment: For the proof of the key identity use $(\arccos(x)+\arccos(-x))'=0$ together wit $\arccos(0_{\pm})=\pi/2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\int_a^bf(x) \ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx$$

$\arccos x+\arccos(-x)=\pi$

Comment: Can you please ellaborate?

Comment: $\arccos$ identity is the key -> (+1)

Comment: In this case doesn't the first eqn amount to observing that the integrand is an even function?  It simplifies things a bit, but you must have an additional idea for the second identity.

Comment: Oh got it thanks . I did see inverse teigo but overlooked it